# Dateparse Function In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field as Hour for one of my business requirements. This tracks hourly   calls for a business. While i add this in tableau, i get the format as "30 Decemeber 1899 11AM" however i only need to display this as time i.e. 11AM, 
12 AM etc.The source of file is excel.

I have used dateparse-
`DATEPARSE ("h:m", [Hour])` and

```
DATEPARSE ("h'h' m'm' s's'", [Hour])
```

but for both i get the error as -

> "Dateparse is being called with (string,datetime), did you mean (string, string)?"

Using 10.2 version.

Comment: Dateparse isn't for formatting fields that are already dates, it is for translating strings into dates. You should use [Hour] as it is but change the format to display only the hour (use the dropdown menu on the hour pill where the "more" submenu will show some time-only formats).

Comment: Tableau supports a string datatype, two numeric datatypes, a date datatype and a datetime datatype. There is no "time" datatype, divorced from the day. Datetime is a compound datatype with 6 components: year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. If you want to represent a time of day independent of the day itself, you need to use a numeric or string datatype.